# webstorm debugging - do not step into scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, nginx, webstorm

New to WebStorm and trying to configure for an upcoming project. I want to exclude library files when debugging (Version 10).

I have the debugger connecting to the site running on chrome, as it is served by a local instance of nginx. I have used Settings >> Build, Execution and Deployment >> Debugger >> Stepping to set the paths of files I don't want to step into. I have tried relative paths, absolute paths and even the the http url paths. No matter what I try, the debugger always seems to step into library code.

Is there any trick to this? Can anyone at least confirm this feature is working for them?

Comment: Have you setup those libraries as [JavaScript Libraries](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2010/11/working-with-javascript-libraries-in-phpstorm-webstorm/) in WebStorm? Together with `Do not step into library scripts` it should do the job.

Comment: I have... one additional issue is the folders are symlinks, so I added the target folders also, still no luck. I guess this feature is not supported when debugging remotely. Thanks.